# Dell M6800 Firepro m6100Gl multi monitor problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-firepro

System: Dell M6800 laptop with the AMD M6100GL Firepro GPU. Windows 8.1

System is docked to the Dell eDock (or whatever it is called) and I am running 4 monitors. 1 is via a USB GPU *(26" 1920x1200) 1 is via the DVI-2 on the docking station (26" 1920x1200) 1 is via the VGA out on the docking (1680x1050) 1 is via the D-port (40" 3480x2160).

Symptom: On a semi-regular basis the screen would all go black as if the GPU was rebooting - causing all my Windows to arrange etc as the monitors slowly sprung back into life. If playing a game full screen on the 40" it caused all end of havoc.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Switch off the "switchable graphics" in the BIOS. This disables the switching between the AMD Firepro and the built in Intel HD GPU - which is there for saving battery life.

The system now only runs on the AMD GPU - I guess the 2 cards were arguing over resources.

No issues at all since done this. Battery life doesn't seem to be affected.